# Redcap Hide one option after select one and more option in Multichoice field in Redcap

Tags: redcap, multichoiceitems

I have a multicoice question in redcap and want to hide one option if i select one or more option from this multichoice filed like:
**Question
What have you done/taken or are currently doing/taking to manage this condition (Polycystic ovary syndrome)?
**
Option in Multichoice

1, Surgery
2, Hormonal medication
3, Anti-diabetic medication
4, Other medication
5, Lifestyle changes (diet, physical activity, etc.)
777, Other
6, No intervention

if i select any one or more option from 1 to 777 then hide option 6

Please  help me out from this. I am new in Redcap

Redcap Hidechoice from multicheck option

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, it sounds like your multiple choice field is also a checkbox field. Your best bet would be to add the `@NONEOFTHEABOVE` Action Tag inside your field using the Online Designer, e.g., `@NONEOFTHEABOVE='6'`. This indicates to REDCap that if option `6, No Intervention` is checked, no other options can be selected. If any other options happen to be selected *first* and *then* the user selects option `6, No Intervention`, REDCap will display a warning to the user that selecting this option will delete their other choices and ask them to confirm. So it'll function very similar to what you're looking for, even though the option won't be hidden.

As far as I'm aware, REDCap cannot *dynamically* hide specific answer choices. REDCap *can* hide entire questions with branching logic or can hide answer choices using the `@IF` and `@HIDECHOICE` action tags, but REDCap evaluates the conditional logic **only** when a survey page or data entry **initially loads**. It does NOT evaluate the conditional logic in real-time. So even if you had something like `@IF(CONDITION, @HIDECHOICE='6', '')`, this would not actually hide option 6 because the question is presumably unanswered when the survey or data entry form is first loaded.

Note: I've also omitted writing out the conditional logic for your specific scenario, as it's quite lengthy because of how REDCap treats checkbox fields.